# Hash as the value of the checked checkbox, remove if uncheck checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

JavaScript:

```
if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')) {
    window.location.hash = this.val();
} else {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
```

My problem is, when I checked checkbox my hash cleared and checkbox value add to hash.

I want when checked, checkbox value append to hash and when unchecked, checkbox value remove from hash.

Comment: thanks to everyone...
solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

First, add the `id` to your `input` tag. Then you need to concatenate the input's value to the hash by first getting the current value of hash (`window.location.hash`). Similarly, when removing, you need to just remove the value part from the hash not the entire hash string.

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mycheckbox").on("change", function(){
      if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')) {
        window.location.hash = window.location.hash + $(this).val();
      }
      else {
        window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace( $(this).val(), '' );                          
      }
    });//change
  });//document ready
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="mycheckbox" value="Bike">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Bike

<script>
$('#mycheckbox').on('change', function(){
    window.location.hash = this.checked ? window.location.hash + this.value : window.location.hash.replace(this.value,'');
});

</script>
```